# How to exclude storage.bucket.list permission on public gcp storage bucket

Tags: gcp

Google Cloud Platform Storage Buckets can be directly exposed via HTTP. The recommended configuration for this is to have `allUsers` with the `Storage Object Viewer` role.

The Storage Object Viewer role has got storage.bucket.list permission. I tried creating a custom role based on this role and removed the storage.bucket.list permission.

I updated the IAM permissions by getting permissions with gcutil, editing, then I tried to update.

When I tried updating I used the following command

`gsutil iam set permissions.txt gs://example.com/`

But I got the following error

> BadRequestException: 400 Role roles/CustomStorageObjectViewer is not
>   supported for this resource.

Is there any way to configure a public gcp storage bucket without the storage.bucket.list permission?

Comment: The Q&A seems to be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54365061/2777965)

Comment: I have the exact same question and I fail to see how the provided link provides an answer.

Comment: @030 Any chance of reopening this question. I believe it was closed by mistake.

Comment: @Todd Q&A has been reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what configs you were using, but here is a process using CLI (gcloud and gsutil). The end product is a new custom role replacing the current standard roles/storage.objectViewer on allUsers for a GCP Bucket.

Recommend using GCP Cloud Cloud Shell in your Project: https://cloud.google.com/shell

1. Create a new Role with the Custom Permissions you would like.

Create yaml file to hold the new config:

```
vi custom_role.yaml
```

Add role configurations to new custom_role.yaml:

```
title: "storageobjectviewer.nolist"
description: "Storage Object Viewer Role without source objects list"
stage: "ALPHA"
includedPermissions:
- resourcemanager.projects.get
- storage.objects.get
```

Create new Role in GCP:

```
gcloud iam roles create storageobjectviewer.nolist --project=[YOUR PROJECT] --file=custom_role.yaml
```

2. Pull current permissions for [YOUR BUCKET] locally:

> gsutil iam get gs://[YOUR BUCKET] > perms.txt

3. Update Permissions with the new role.

Should only be this section:

> ```
> {
>   "members": [
>     "allUsers"
>   ],
>   "role": "projects/[YOUR PROJECT]/roles/storageobjectviewer.nolist"
> }
> ```

4. Update the allUsers to the new role on [YOUR BUCKET]

> gsutil iam set perms.txt  gs://[YOUR BUCKET]

The new configuration should be viewable in CLI:

```
gsutil iam get gs://[YOUR BUCKET]
```

Also in the UI:
Bucket Details -> Permissions
[image]

and IAM -> Roles
[image]
Hopefully this helps!

Additional Info:

- https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#iam-custom-roles-create-gcloud
- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/iam
- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#gsutil
- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles